# SVG hover won't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, hover

I have a fairly large SVG and there are specific paths that change when hovered on. This works in Chrome but not Firefox.
Each section that is to be animated is nested in a link tag, the hover effect is to make it look like the section is expanding. Any assistance as to why this does not work in Firefox is appreciated. Also not that looking through the debugger it appears Firefox recognize the hover event but is ignore the new path.

```css
#matrice1:hover #sec1 {
  d: path("M480.03,200.899l68.21-175.566C509.431,10.447,450.037,0,405.989,0 l-0.106,187.383C431.991,187.383,456.979,192.173,480.03,200.899");
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 808 798" enable-background="new 0 0 800 798">
<a href="#" class="matrixSection matrixNav" onclick="animateMatrix(1)" id="matrice1">
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" id="sec1" fill="#E7223B" d="M480.03,200.899l50.842-130.106c-38.81-14.886-80.941-23.066-124.989-23.066
       v139.656C431.991,187.383,456.979,192.173,480.03,200.899"/>
      <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M480.03,200.899
       l50.842-130.106c-38.81-14.886-80.941-23.066-124.989-23.066v139.656C431.991,187.383,456.979,192.173,480.03,200.899z"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#932826" d="M475.407,212.728l4.623-11.829c-23.051-8.727-48.039-13.517-74.147-13.517
         v12.695C430.36,200.078,453.789,204.56,475.407,212.728"/>
       <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M475.407,212.728l4.623-11.829
         c-23.051-8.727-48.039-13.517-74.147-13.517v12.695C430.36,200.078,453.789,204.56,475.407,212.728z"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#932826" d="M450.935,275.354l24.473-62.626c-21.618-8.166-45.047-12.649-69.524-12.649
           v67.277C421.72,267.354,436.894,270.184,450.935,275.354"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M450.935,275.354l24.473-62.626
           c-21.618-8.166-45.047-12.649-69.524-12.649v67.277C421.72,267.354,436.894,270.184,450.935,275.354z"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#E7223B" d="M447.761,283.476l3.174-8.122c-14.041-5.17-29.215-7.999-45.052-7.999v8.723
             C420.599,276.078,434.704,278.69,447.761,283.476"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M447.761,283.476
             l3.174-8.122c-14.041-5.17-29.215-7.999-45.052-7.999v8.723C420.599,276.078,434.704,278.69,447.761,283.476z"/>

                <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M455.612,229.054c0.185-0.848,1.027-1.384,1.874-1.198
               c0.85,0.186,1.386,1.024,1.198,1.875c-0.187,0.849-1.024,1.386-1.873,1.199C455.963,230.743,455.424,229.904,455.612,229.054"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M458.478,231.918c1.02,0.324,1.645,1.38,1.41,2.45l-0.113,0.51l-0.049,0.224
               l-0.777,3.525c-0.07,0.327-0.397,0.536-0.727,0.463c-0.328-0.072-0.535-0.397-0.464-0.725l0.806-3.658
               c0.03-0.138,0.031-0.332-0.22-0.389c-0.175-0.039-0.251,0.137-0.282,0.255l-2.412,10.964c-0.104,0.473-0.568,0.771-1.044,0.668
               c-0.474-0.105-0.772-0.572-0.669-1.044l1.39-6.319c0.012-0.07,0.027-0.257-0.188-0.305h-0.003
               c-0.218-0.048-0.282,0.127-0.301,0.198l-1.389,6.319c-0.104,0.471-0.57,0.772-1.045,0.667c-0.474-0.104-0.771-0.573-0.666-1.043
               l2.411-10.967c0.021-0.118,0.021-0.311-0.149-0.35c-0.252-0.054-0.331,0.124-0.362,0.261l-0.803,3.659
               c-0.073,0.326-0.4,0.537-0.729,0.464c-0.328-0.072-0.534-0.399-0.463-0.726l0.775-3.527l0.05-0.222l0.112-0.512
               c0.234-1.07,1.245-1.767,2.312-1.632c0.033,0.004,0.073,0.007,0.111,0.016l1.686,0.371l1.676,0.368
               C458.404,231.891,458.438,231.905,458.478,231.918"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M446.297,227.854c0.176-0.805-0.327-1.601-1.134-1.777
               c-0.805-0.177-1.602,0.333-1.776,1.137c-0.177,0.802,0.33,1.597,1.136,1.775C445.326,229.166,446.12,228.657,446.297,227.854"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M441.185,230.184l-2.075,3.672c0,0-0.374,0.674,0.198,0.989
               c0.568,0.315,0.909-0.351,0.909-0.351l1.699-3.072c0,0,0.106-0.241,0.287-0.144c0.178,0.097,0.047,0.351,0.047,0.351l-3.053,5.788
               l1.577,0.347l-0.969,4.41c-0.092,0.419,0.174,0.832,0.592,0.924c0.42,0.092,0.833-0.173,0.924-0.591l0.971-4.41l0.217,0.046
               l0.214,0.045l-0.972,4.413c-0.091,0.419,0.173,0.832,0.593,0.923c0.422,0.095,0.835-0.173,0.926-0.59l0.971-4.411l1.578,0.348
               l-0.341-6.533c0,0-0.014-0.285,0.188-0.3c0.202-0.012,0.2,0.252,0.2,0.252l0.252,3.502c0,0,0.031,0.745,0.678,0.699
               c0.655-0.045,0.596-0.815,0.596-0.815l-0.342-4.206c0,0-0.181-1.23-1.139-1.442l-1.543-0.339l-1.542-0.34
               C441.868,229.142,441.185,230.184,441.185,230.184"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M437.58,225.936c0.176-0.804-0.328-1.601-1.133-1.777
               c-0.805-0.177-1.601,0.333-1.778,1.137c-0.177,0.803,0.332,1.599,1.136,1.775C436.608,227.249,437.402,226.741,437.58,225.936"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M432.469,228.268l-2.075,3.671c0,0-0.376,0.675,0.198,0.99
               c0.568,0.316,0.908-0.348,0.908-0.348l1.699-3.072c0,0,0.107-0.243,0.286-0.146c0.18,0.097,0.047,0.351,0.047,0.351l-3.052,5.787
               l1.578,0.347l-0.971,4.412c-0.091,0.417,0.178,0.831,0.595,0.923c0.417,0.092,0.831-0.174,0.924-0.592l0.969-4.41l0.219,0.047
               l0.214,0.048l-0.973,4.411c-0.09,0.417,0.173,0.832,0.594,0.924c0.418,0.093,0.833-0.173,0.924-0.59l0.972-4.412l1.577,0.348
               l-0.34-6.533c0,0-0.016-0.286,0.187-0.3c0.203-0.014,0.201,0.253,0.201,0.253l0.252,3.5c0,0,0.03,0.746,0.677,0.7
               c0.654-0.046,0.595-0.816,0.595-0.816l-0.341-4.205c0,0-0.179-1.231-1.14-1.442l-1.54-0.339l-1.544-0.339
               C433.151,227.225,432.469,228.268,432.469,228.268"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M449.394,237.072c0.669,0.146,1.327-0.277,1.476-0.947
               c0.148-0.669-0.274-1.329-0.944-1.477c-0.669-0.146-1.331,0.274-1.477,0.945C448.299,236.263,448.722,236.926,449.394,237.072"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M445.659,240.196c-0.088,0.129-0.204,0.417,0.053,0.612
               c0.298,0.228,0.556-0.054,0.556-0.054l1.118-1.954c0,0,0.144-0.117,0.116,0.029l-1.088,4.944h0.004
               c-0.077,0.343,0.139,0.681,0.483,0.758c0.342,0.074,0.682-0.142,0.757-0.485l0.43-1.951c0,0,0.023-0.284,0.249-0.235
               c0.221,0.049,0.126,0.318,0.126,0.318l-0.429,1.949c-0.076,0.345,0.143,0.684,0.486,0.758c0.343,0.076,0.684-0.14,0.759-0.483
               l1.088-4.945c0.028-0.144,0.085-0.024,0.085-0.024l0.2,1.55c0,0,0.082,0.693,0.145,0.737c0.212,0.149,0.505,0.098,0.657-0.117
               c0.097-0.137,0.108-0.308,0.044-0.454l0.008-0.002c-0.008-0.049-0.354-2.074-0.385-2.351c-0.099-0.857-0.595-0.96-1.072-1.079
               c-0.478-0.118-0.766-0.169-0.766-0.169s-0.303-0.079-0.942-0.201c-0.635-0.118-0.903,0.163-1.992,1.799
               c-0.158,0.236-0.677,0.997-0.692,1.047L445.659,240.196z"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M424.761,222.271c0.188-0.849-0.35-1.688-1.2-1.876
               c-0.847-0.187-1.686,0.351-1.871,1.201c-0.188,0.847,0.346,1.689,1.195,1.874C423.732,223.656,424.574,223.119,424.761,222.271"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M420.961,223.667c-1.065-0.135-2.075,0.563-2.311,1.632l-0.112,0.509
               l-0.048,0.224l-0.777,3.526c-0.07,0.33,0.137,0.654,0.467,0.728c0.329,0.071,0.655-0.135,0.727-0.464l0.805-3.658
               c0.029-0.139,0.11-0.315,0.361-0.258c0.174,0.038,0.167,0.229,0.15,0.347l-2.411,10.966c-0.104,0.473,0.191,0.941,0.667,1.045
               c0.474,0.104,0.939-0.197,1.044-0.668l1.391-6.32c0.018-0.069,0.08-0.243,0.299-0.196c0.218,0.048,0.204,0.234,0.193,0.305
               l-1.392,6.318c-0.103,0.472,0.195,0.942,0.667,1.047c0.473,0.103,0.939-0.199,1.046-0.669l2.411-10.967
               c0.031-0.116,0.109-0.29,0.282-0.254c0.25,0.056,0.248,0.25,0.219,0.389l-0.805,3.658c-0.072,0.326,0.137,0.653,0.465,0.726
               c0.329,0.073,0.654-0.137,0.727-0.465l0.775-3.524l0.049-0.225l0.111-0.51c0.236-1.07-0.388-2.127-1.412-2.45
               c-0.033-0.012-0.068-0.023-0.11-0.035l-1.682-0.371l-1.679-0.368C421.037,223.673,420.996,223.671,420.961,223.667"/>

 <line clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.307" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="418.099" y1="230.292" x2="415.143" y2="237.227"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M425.78,231.214c-0.054-0.143-0.172-0.256-0.328-0.289
               c-0.244-0.053-0.484,0.101-0.538,0.344c-0.016,0.071,0,0.202,0,0.202l0.735,2.477c0,0,0.04,0.17,0.01,0.309l-1.044,4.745h0.005
               c-0.074,0.333,0.133,0.656,0.465,0.728c0.33,0.074,0.652-0.134,0.726-0.464l0.412-1.875c0,0,0.025-0.27,0.238-0.225
               c0.213,0.048,0.121,0.305,0.121,0.305l-0.411,1.875c-0.074,0.33,0.137,0.654,0.467,0.727c0.329,0.071,0.656-0.135,0.729-0.465
               l1.045-4.747c0.029-0.14,0.137-0.275,0.137-0.275l1.578-1.792c0,0,0.202-0.262,0.218-0.332c0.054-0.242-0.101-0.484-0.344-0.538
               c-0.162-0.036-0.315,0.02-0.42,0.125l-0.005-0.003c-0.042,0.022-0.829,0.906-1.055,1.049c-0.243,0.158-0.413,0.096-0.413,0.096
               l-0.737-0.163l-0.732-0.161c0,0-0.183-0.016-0.335-0.259c-0.148-0.229-0.488-1.358-0.518-1.397L425.78,231.214z"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M427.538,232.267c0.671,0.146,1.33-0.276,1.479-0.947
               c0.147-0.669-0.274-1.329-0.944-1.477c-0.67-0.146-1.329,0.274-1.477,0.945C426.445,231.457,426.87,232.12,427.538,232.267"/>
              <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="427.168,233.967 428.316,235.267 428.438,237.805 426.421,237.361
               424.399,236.917 425.577,234.664   "/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M455.612,229.054c0.185-0.848,1.027-1.384,1.874-1.198
               c0.85,0.186,1.386,1.024,1.198,1.875c-0.187,0.849-1.024,1.386-1.873,1.199C455.963,230.743,455.424,229.904,455.612,229.054"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M458.478,231.918c1.02,0.324,1.645,1.38,1.41,2.45l-0.113,0.51l-0.049,0.224
               l-0.777,3.525c-0.07,0.327-0.397,0.536-0.727,0.463c-0.328-0.072-0.535-0.397-0.464-0.725l0.806-3.658
               c0.03-0.138,0.031-0.332-0.22-0.389c-0.175-0.039-0.251,0.137-0.282,0.255l-2.412,10.964c-0.104,0.473-0.568,0.771-1.044,0.668
               c-0.474-0.105-0.772-0.572-0.669-1.044l1.39-6.319c0.012-0.07,0.027-0.257-0.188-0.305h-0.003
               c-0.218-0.048-0.282,0.127-0.301,0.198l-1.389,6.319c-0.104,0.471-0.57,0.772-1.045,0.667c-0.474-0.104-0.771-0.573-0.666-1.043
               l2.411-10.967c0.021-0.118,0.021-0.311-0.149-0.35c-0.252-0.054-0.331,0.124-0.362,0.261l-0.803,3.659
               c-0.073,0.326-0.4,0.537-0.729,0.464c-0.328-0.072-0.534-0.399-0.463-0.726l0.775-3.527l0.05-0.222l0.112-0.512
               c0.234-1.07,1.245-1.767,2.312-1.632c0.033,0.004,0.073,0.007,0.111,0.016l1.686,0.371l1.676,0.368
               C458.404,231.891,458.438,231.905,458.478,231.918"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M446.297,227.854c0.176-0.805-0.327-1.601-1.134-1.777
               c-0.805-0.177-1.602,0.333-1.776,1.137c-0.177,0.802,0.33,1.597,1.136,1.775C445.326,229.166,446.12,228.657,446.297,227.854"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M441.185,230.184l-2.075,3.672c0,0-0.374,0.674,0.198,0.989
               c0.568,0.315,0.909-0.351,0.909-0.351l1.699-3.072c0,0,0.106-0.241,0.287-0.144c0.178,0.097,0.047,0.351,0.047,0.351l-3.053,5.788
               l1.577,0.347l-0.969,4.41c-0.092,0.419,0.174,0.832,0.592,0.924c0.42,0.092,0.833-0.173,0.924-0.591l0.971-4.41l0.217,0.046
               l0.214,0.045l-0.972,4.413c-0.091,0.419,0.173,0.832,0.593,0.923c0.422,0.095,0.835-0.173,0.926-0.59l0.971-4.411l1.578,0.348
               l-0.341-6.533c0,0-0.014-0.285,0.188-0.3c0.202-0.012,0.2,0.252,0.2,0.252l0.252,3.502c0,0,0.031,0.745,0.678,0.699
               c0.655-0.045,0.596-0.815,0.596-0.815l-0.342-4.206c0,0-0.181-1.23-1.139-1.442l-1.543-0.339l-1.542-0.34
               C441.868,229.142,441.185,230.184,441.185,230.184"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M437.58,225.936c0.176-0.804-0.328-1.601-1.133-1.777
               c-0.805-0.177-1.601,0.333-1.778,1.137c-0.177,0.803,0.332,1.599,1.136,1.775C436.608,227.249,437.402,226.741,437.58,225.936"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M432.469,228.268l-2.075,3.671c0,0-0.376,0.675,0.198,0.99
               c0.568,0.316,0.908-0.348,0.908-0.348l1.699-3.072c0,0,0.107-0.243,0.286-0.146c0.18,0.097,0.047,0.351,0.047,0.351l-3.052,5.787
               l1.578,0.347l-0.971,4.412c-0.091,0.417,0.178,0.831,0.595,0.923c0.417,0.092,0.831-0.174,0.924-0.592l0.969-4.41l0.219,0.047
               l0.214,0.048l-0.973,4.411c-0.09,0.417,0.173,0.832,0.594,0.924c0.418,0.093,0.833-0.173,0.924-0.59l0.972-4.412l1.577,0.348
               l-0.34-6.533c0,0-0.016-0.286,0.187-0.3c0.203-0.014,0.201,0.253,0.201,0.253l0.252,3.5c0,0,0.03,0.746,0.677,0.7
               c0.654-0.046,0.595-0.816,0.595-0.816l-0.341-4.205c0,0-0.179-1.231-1.14-1.442l-1.54-0.339l-1.544-0.339
               C433.151,227.225,432.469,228.268,432.469,228.268"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M449.394,237.072c0.669,0.146,1.327-0.277,1.476-0.947
               c0.148-0.669-0.274-1.329-0.944-1.477c-0.669-0.146-1.331,0.274-1.477,0.945C448.299,236.263,448.722,236.926,449.394,237.072"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M445.659,240.196c-0.088,0.129-0.204,0.417,0.053,0.612
               c0.298,0.228,0.556-0.054,0.556-0.054l1.118-1.954c0,0,0.144-0.117,0.116,0.029l-1.088,4.944h0.004
               c-0.077,0.343,0.139,0.681,0.483,0.758c0.342,0.074,0.682-0.142,0.757-0.485l0.43-1.951c0,0,0.023-0.284,0.249-0.235
               c0.221,0.049,0.126,0.318,0.126,0.318l-0.429,1.949c-0.076,0.345,0.143,0.684,0.486,0.758c0.343,0.076,0.684-0.14,0.759-0.483
               l1.088-4.945c0.028-0.144,0.085-0.024,0.085-0.024l0.2,1.55c0,0,0.082,0.693,0.145,0.737c0.212,0.149,0.505,0.098,0.657-0.117
               c0.097-0.137,0.108-0.308,0.044-0.454l0.008-0.002c-0.008-0.049-0.354-2.074-0.385-2.351c-0.099-0.857-0.595-0.96-1.072-1.079
               c-0.478-0.118-0.766-0.169-0.766-0.169s-0.303-0.079-0.942-0.201c-0.635-0.118-0.903,0.163-1.992,1.799
               c-0.158,0.236-0.677,0.997-0.692,1.047L445.659,240.196z"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M424.761,222.271c0.188-0.849-0.35-1.688-1.2-1.876
               c-0.847-0.187-1.686,0.351-1.871,1.201c-0.188,0.847,0.346,1.689,1.195,1.874C423.732,223.656,424.574,223.119,424.761,222.271"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M420.961,223.667c-1.065-0.135-2.075,0.563-2.311,1.632l-0.112,0.509
               l-0.048,0.224l-0.777,3.526c-0.07,0.33,0.137,0.654,0.467,0.728c0.329,0.071,0.655-0.135,0.727-0.464l0.805-3.658
               c0.029-0.139,0.11-0.315,0.361-0.258c0.174,0.038,0.167,0.229,0.15,0.347l-2.411,10.966c-0.104,0.473,0.191,0.941,0.667,1.045
               c0.474,0.104,0.939-0.197,1.044-0.668l1.391-6.32c0.018-0.069,0.08-0.243,0.299-0.196c0.218,0.048,0.204,0.234,0.193,0.305
               l-1.392,6.318c-0.103,0.472,0.195,0.942,0.667,1.047c0.473,0.103,0.939-0.199,1.046-0.669l2.411-10.967
               c0.031-0.116,0.109-0.29,0.282-0.254c0.25,0.056,0.248,0.25,0.219,0.389l-0.805,3.658c-0.072,0.326,0.137,0.653,0.465,0.726
               c0.329,0.073,0.654-0.137,0.727-0.465l0.775-3.524l0.049-0.225l0.111-0.51c0.236-1.07-0.388-2.127-1.412-2.45
               c-0.033-0.012-0.068-0.023-0.11-0.035l-1.682-0.371l-1.679-0.368C421.037,223.673,420.996,223.671,420.961,223.667"/>
               <line clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.307" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="418.099" y1="230.292" x2="415.143" y2="237.227"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M425.78,231.214c-0.054-0.143-0.172-0.256-0.328-0.289
               c-0.244-0.053-0.484,0.101-0.538,0.344c-0.016,0.071,0,0.202,0,0.202l0.735,2.477c0,0,0.04,0.17,0.01,0.309l-1.044,4.745h0.005
               c-0.074,0.333,0.133,0.656,0.465,0.728c0.33,0.074,0.652-0.134,0.726-0.464l0.412-1.875c0,0,0.025-0.27,0.238-0.225
               c0.213,0.048,0.121,0.305,0.121,0.305l-0.411,1.875c-0.074,0.33,0.137,0.654,0.467,0.727c0.329,0.071,0.656-0.135,0.729-0.465
               l1.045-4.747c0.029-0.14,0.137-0.275,0.137-0.275l1.578-1.792c0,0,0.202-0.262,0.218-0.332c0.054-0.242-0.101-0.484-0.344-0.538
               c-0.162-0.036-0.315,0.02-0.42,0.125l-0.005-0.003c-0.042,0.022-0.829,0.906-1.055,1.049c-0.243,0.158-0.413,0.096-0.413,0.096
               l-0.737-0.163l-0.732-0.161c0,0-0.183-0.016-0.335-0.259c-0.148-0.229-0.488-1.358-0.518-1.397L425.78,231.214z"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M427.538,232.267c0.671,0.146,1.33-0.276,1.479-0.947
               c0.147-0.669-0.274-1.329-0.944-1.477c-0.67-0.146-1.329,0.274-1.477,0.945C426.445,231.457,426.87,232.12,427.538,232.267"/>
              <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="427.168,233.967 428.316,235.267 428.438,237.805 426.421,237.361
               424.399,236.917 425.577,234.664   "/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="456.941,77.504 456.98,77.504 456.98,99.654 461.847,99.654
                 461.847,70.718 457.963,70.718 453.481,75.967 453.481,81.045 453.524,81.045   "/>
                    <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="436.893,124.923 436.893,130.997 435.522,130.997 435.522,121.33
                   437.118,121.33 438.872,126.875 438.872,121.33 440.227,121.33 440.227,130.997 438.801,130.997   "/>
                  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M441.151,128.501v-4.675c0-1.512,0.741-2.61,2.45-2.61
                   c1.728,0,2.468,1.098,2.468,2.61v4.675c0,1.498-0.74,2.611-2.468,2.611C441.893,131.112,441.151,130,441.151,128.501
                    M444.445,128.759v-5.189c0-0.583-0.259-0.998-0.844-0.998c-0.568,0-0.824,0.415-0.824,0.998v5.189
                   c0,0.585,0.256,0.997,0.824,0.997C444.187,129.756,444.445,129.344,444.445,128.759"/>
                  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M435.522,134.873h2.409c1.64,0,2.238,0.813,2.238,2.167v2.038
                   c0,1.354-0.599,2.181-2.238,2.181h-0.785v3.28h-1.624V134.873z M437.146,136.198v3.807h0.602c0.555,0,0.795-0.271,0.795-0.799
                   v-2.224c0-0.527-0.24-0.784-0.795-0.784H437.146z"/>
                  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M441.01,142.043v-4.675c0-1.512,0.741-2.609,2.451-2.609
                   c1.726,0,2.467,1.098,2.467,2.609v4.675c0,1.499-0.741,2.608-2.467,2.608C441.751,144.651,441.01,143.542,441.01,142.043
                    M444.304,142.301v-5.19c0-0.585-0.259-0.998-0.843-0.998c-0.569,0-0.826,0.413-0.826,0.998v5.19c0,0.585,0.257,0.997,0.826,0.997
                   C444.045,143.298,444.304,142.886,444.304,142.301"/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="451.772,134.872 449.933,144.538 448.165,144.538 446.324,134.872
                   447.98,134.872 449.091,141.617 449.104,141.617 450.246,134.872   "/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="452.44,134.872 456.319,134.872 456.319,136.197 454.067,136.197
                   454.067,138.964 455.678,138.964 455.678,140.274 454.067,140.274 454.067,143.213 456.319,143.213 456.319,144.538
                   452.44,144.538   "/>
                  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M458.813,140.105v4.434h-1.627v-9.667h2.369c1.638,0,2.237,0.813,2.237,2.167
                   v1.239c0,1.042-0.372,1.655-1.299,1.869l1.555,4.392h-1.711L458.813,140.105z M458.813,136.198v3.008h0.542
                   c0.555,0,0.798-0.285,0.798-0.798v-1.426c0-0.527-0.243-0.784-0.798-0.784H458.813z"/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="462.347,134.872 466.669,134.872 466.669,136.197 465.327,136.197
                   465.327,144.538 463.688,144.538 463.688,136.197 462.347,136.197   "/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="470.586,140.86 470.586,144.538 468.963,144.538 468.963,140.86
                   467.151,134.872 468.85,134.872 469.832,138.535 469.844,138.535 470.83,134.872 472.383,134.872   "/>
      </a>
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling the `d` attribute with CSS is a new SVG2 thing that Chrome has implemented, but Firefox has not, yet.

**Update**

You can achieve the same effect using SVGs built-in SMIL animation features.  This will work on most browsers - except IE and Edge.  If you need to support those browsers also, you will need to switch the path using Javascript (in a mouse event handler).

```
<path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" id="sec1" fill="#E7223B" d="...initial path...">
  <set attributeName="d" to="...new path..."
       begin="matrice1.mouseover" end="matrice1.mouseout"/>
</path>
```

Demo:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 808 798" enable-background="new 0 0 800 798">
<a href="#" class="matrixSection matrixNav" onclick="animateMatrix(1)" id="matrice1">
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" id="sec1" fill="#E7223B" d="M480.03,200.899l50.842-130.106c-38.81-14.886-80.941-23.066-124.989-23.066
       v139.656C431.991,187.383,456.979,192.173,480.03,200.899">
          <set attributeName="d" to="M480.03,200.899l68.21-175.566C509.431,10.447,450.037,0,405.989,0 l-0.106,187.383C431.991,187.383,456.979,192.173,480.03,200.899"
               begin="matrice1.mouseover" end="matrice1.mouseout"/>
        </path>
      <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M480.03,200.899
       l50.842-130.106c-38.81-14.886-80.941-23.066-124.989-23.066v139.656C431.991,187.383,456.979,192.173,480.03,200.899z"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#932826" d="M475.407,212.728l4.623-11.829c-23.051-8.727-48.039-13.517-74.147-13.517
         v12.695C430.36,200.078,453.789,204.56,475.407,212.728"/>
       <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M475.407,212.728l4.623-11.829
         c-23.051-8.727-48.039-13.517-74.147-13.517v12.695C430.36,200.078,453.789,204.56,475.407,212.728z"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#932826" d="M450.935,275.354l24.473-62.626c-21.618-8.166-45.047-12.649-69.524-12.649
           v67.277C421.72,267.354,436.894,270.184,450.935,275.354"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M450.935,275.354l24.473-62.626
           c-21.618-8.166-45.047-12.649-69.524-12.649v67.277C421.72,267.354,436.894,270.184,450.935,275.354z"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#E7223B" d="M447.761,283.476l3.174-8.122c-14.041-5.17-29.215-7.999-45.052-7.999v8.723
             C420.599,276.078,434.704,278.69,447.761,283.476"/>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M447.761,283.476
             l3.174-8.122c-14.041-5.17-29.215-7.999-45.052-7.999v8.723C420.599,276.078,434.704,278.69,447.761,283.476z"/>

                <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M455.612,229.054c0.185-0.848,1.027-1.384,1.874-1.198
               c0.85,0.186,1.386,1.024,1.198,1.875c-0.187,0.849-1.024,1.386-1.873,1.199C455.963,230.743,455.424,229.904,455.612,229.054"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M458.478,231.918c1.02,0.324,1.645,1.38,1.41,2.45l-0.113,0.51l-0.049,0.224
               l-0.777,3.525c-0.07,0.327-0.397,0.536-0.727,0.463c-0.328-0.072-0.535-0.397-0.464-0.725l0.806-3.658
               c0.03-0.138,0.031-0.332-0.22-0.389c-0.175-0.039-0.251,0.137-0.282,0.255l-2.412,10.964c-0.104,0.473-0.568,0.771-1.044,0.668
               c-0.474-0.105-0.772-0.572-0.669-1.044l1.39-6.319c0.012-0.07,0.027-0.257-0.188-0.305h-0.003
               c-0.218-0.048-0.282,0.127-0.301,0.198l-1.389,6.319c-0.104,0.471-0.57,0.772-1.045,0.667c-0.474-0.104-0.771-0.573-0.666-1.043
               l2.411-10.967c0.021-0.118,0.021-0.311-0.149-0.35c-0.252-0.054-0.331,0.124-0.362,0.261l-0.803,3.659
               c-0.073,0.326-0.4,0.537-0.729,0.464c-0.328-0.072-0.534-0.399-0.463-0.726l0.775-3.527l0.05-0.222l0.112-0.512
               c0.234-1.07,1.245-1.767,2.312-1.632c0.033,0.004,0.073,0.007,0.111,0.016l1.686,0.371l1.676,0.368
               C458.404,231.891,458.438,231.905,458.478,231.918"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M446.297,227.854c0.176-0.805-0.327-1.601-1.134-1.777
               c-0.805-0.177-1.602,0.333-1.776,1.137c-0.177,0.802,0.33,1.597,1.136,1.775C445.326,229.166,446.12,228.657,446.297,227.854"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M441.185,230.184l-2.075,3.672c0,0-0.374,0.674,0.198,0.989
               c0.568,0.315,0.909-0.351,0.909-0.351l1.699-3.072c0,0,0.106-0.241,0.287-0.144c0.178,0.097,0.047,0.351,0.047,0.351l-3.053,5.788
               l1.577,0.347l-0.969,4.41c-0.092,0.419,0.174,0.832,0.592,0.924c0.42,0.092,0.833-0.173,0.924-0.591l0.971-4.41l0.217,0.046
               l0.214,0.045l-0.972,4.413c-0.091,0.419,0.173,0.832,0.593,0.923c0.422,0.095,0.835-0.173,0.926-0.59l0.971-4.411l1.578,0.348
               l-0.341-6.533c0,0-0.014-0.285,0.188-0.3c0.202-0.012,0.2,0.252,0.2,0.252l0.252,3.502c0,0,0.031,0.745,0.678,0.699
               c0.655-0.045,0.596-0.815,0.596-0.815l-0.342-4.206c0,0-0.181-1.23-1.139-1.442l-1.543-0.339l-1.542-0.34
               C441.868,229.142,441.185,230.184,441.185,230.184"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M437.58,225.936c0.176-0.804-0.328-1.601-1.133-1.777
               c-0.805-0.177-1.601,0.333-1.778,1.137c-0.177,0.803,0.332,1.599,1.136,1.775C436.608,227.249,437.402,226.741,437.58,225.936"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M432.469,228.268l-2.075,3.671c0,0-0.376,0.675,0.198,0.99
               c0.568,0.316,0.908-0.348,0.908-0.348l1.699-3.072c0,0,0.107-0.243,0.286-0.146c0.18,0.097,0.047,0.351,0.047,0.351l-3.052,5.787
               l1.578,0.347l-0.971,4.412c-0.091,0.417,0.178,0.831,0.595,0.923c0.417,0.092,0.831-0.174,0.924-0.592l0.969-4.41l0.219,0.047
               l0.214,0.048l-0.973,4.411c-0.09,0.417,0.173,0.832,0.594,0.924c0.418,0.093,0.833-0.173,0.924-0.59l0.972-4.412l1.577,0.348
               l-0.34-6.533c0,0-0.016-0.286,0.187-0.3c0.203-0.014,0.201,0.253,0.201,0.253l0.252,3.5c0,0,0.03,0.746,0.677,0.7
               c0.654-0.046,0.595-0.816,0.595-0.816l-0.341-4.205c0,0-0.179-1.231-1.14-1.442l-1.54-0.339l-1.544-0.339
               C433.151,227.225,432.469,228.268,432.469,228.268"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M449.394,237.072c0.669,0.146,1.327-0.277,1.476-0.947
               c0.148-0.669-0.274-1.329-0.944-1.477c-0.669-0.146-1.331,0.274-1.477,0.945C448.299,236.263,448.722,236.926,449.394,237.072"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M445.659,240.196c-0.088,0.129-0.204,0.417,0.053,0.612
               c0.298,0.228,0.556-0.054,0.556-0.054l1.118-1.954c0,0,0.144-0.117,0.116,0.029l-1.088,4.944h0.004
               c-0.077,0.343,0.139,0.681,0.483,0.758c0.342,0.074,0.682-0.142,0.757-0.485l0.43-1.951c0,0,0.023-0.284,0.249-0.235
               c0.221,0.049,0.126,0.318,0.126,0.318l-0.429,1.949c-0.076,0.345,0.143,0.684,0.486,0.758c0.343,0.076,0.684-0.14,0.759-0.483
               l1.088-4.945c0.028-0.144,0.085-0.024,0.085-0.024l0.2,1.55c0,0,0.082,0.693,0.145,0.737c0.212,0.149,0.505,0.098,0.657-0.117
               c0.097-0.137,0.108-0.308,0.044-0.454l0.008-0.002c-0.008-0.049-0.354-2.074-0.385-2.351c-0.099-0.857-0.595-0.96-1.072-1.079
               c-0.478-0.118-0.766-0.169-0.766-0.169s-0.303-0.079-0.942-0.201c-0.635-0.118-0.903,0.163-1.992,1.799
               c-0.158,0.236-0.677,0.997-0.692,1.047L445.659,240.196z"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M424.761,222.271c0.188-0.849-0.35-1.688-1.2-1.876
               c-0.847-0.187-1.686,0.351-1.871,1.201c-0.188,0.847,0.346,1.689,1.195,1.874C423.732,223.656,424.574,223.119,424.761,222.271"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M420.961,223.667c-1.065-0.135-2.075,0.563-2.311,1.632l-0.112,0.509
               l-0.048,0.224l-0.777,3.526c-0.07,0.33,0.137,0.654,0.467,0.728c0.329,0.071,0.655-0.135,0.727-0.464l0.805-3.658
               c0.029-0.139,0.11-0.315,0.361-0.258c0.174,0.038,0.167,0.229,0.15,0.347l-2.411,10.966c-0.104,0.473,0.191,0.941,0.667,1.045
               c0.474,0.104,0.939-0.197,1.044-0.668l1.391-6.32c0.018-0.069,0.08-0.243,0.299-0.196c0.218,0.048,0.204,0.234,0.193,0.305
               l-1.392,6.318c-0.103,0.472,0.195,0.942,0.667,1.047c0.473,0.103,0.939-0.199,1.046-0.669l2.411-10.967
               c0.031-0.116,0.109-0.29,0.282-0.254c0.25,0.056,0.248,0.25,0.219,0.389l-0.805,3.658c-0.072,0.326,0.137,0.653,0.465,0.726
               c0.329,0.073,0.654-0.137,0.727-0.465l0.775-3.524l0.049-0.225l0.111-0.51c0.236-1.07-0.388-2.127-1.412-2.45
               c-0.033-0.012-0.068-0.023-0.11-0.035l-1.682-0.371l-1.679-0.368C421.037,223.673,420.996,223.671,420.961,223.667"/>

 <line clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.307" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="418.099" y1="230.292" x2="415.143" y2="237.227"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M425.78,231.214c-0.054-0.143-0.172-0.256-0.328-0.289
               c-0.244-0.053-0.484,0.101-0.538,0.344c-0.016,0.071,0,0.202,0,0.202l0.735,2.477c0,0,0.04,0.17,0.01,0.309l-1.044,4.745h0.005
               c-0.074,0.333,0.133,0.656,0.465,0.728c0.33,0.074,0.652-0.134,0.726-0.464l0.412-1.875c0,0,0.025-0.27,0.238-0.225
               c0.213,0.048,0.121,0.305,0.121,0.305l-0.411,1.875c-0.074,0.33,0.137,0.654,0.467,0.727c0.329,0.071,0.656-0.135,0.729-0.465
               l1.045-4.747c0.029-0.14,0.137-0.275,0.137-0.275l1.578-1.792c0,0,0.202-0.262,0.218-0.332c0.054-0.242-0.101-0.484-0.344-0.538
               c-0.162-0.036-0.315,0.02-0.42,0.125l-0.005-0.003c-0.042,0.022-0.829,0.906-1.055,1.049c-0.243,0.158-0.413,0.096-0.413,0.096
               l-0.737-0.163l-0.732-0.161c0,0-0.183-0.016-0.335-0.259c-0.148-0.229-0.488-1.358-0.518-1.397L425.78,231.214z"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M427.538,232.267c0.671,0.146,1.33-0.276,1.479-0.947
               c0.147-0.669-0.274-1.329-0.944-1.477c-0.67-0.146-1.329,0.274-1.477,0.945C426.445,231.457,426.87,232.12,427.538,232.267"/>
              <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="427.168,233.967 428.316,235.267 428.438,237.805 426.421,237.361
               424.399,236.917 425.577,234.664   "/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M455.612,229.054c0.185-0.848,1.027-1.384,1.874-1.198
               c0.85,0.186,1.386,1.024,1.198,1.875c-0.187,0.849-1.024,1.386-1.873,1.199C455.963,230.743,455.424,229.904,455.612,229.054"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M458.478,231.918c1.02,0.324,1.645,1.38,1.41,2.45l-0.113,0.51l-0.049,0.224
               l-0.777,3.525c-0.07,0.327-0.397,0.536-0.727,0.463c-0.328-0.072-0.535-0.397-0.464-0.725l0.806-3.658
               c0.03-0.138,0.031-0.332-0.22-0.389c-0.175-0.039-0.251,0.137-0.282,0.255l-2.412,10.964c-0.104,0.473-0.568,0.771-1.044,0.668
               c-0.474-0.105-0.772-0.572-0.669-1.044l1.39-6.319c0.012-0.07,0.027-0.257-0.188-0.305h-0.003
               c-0.218-0.048-0.282,0.127-0.301,0.198l-1.389,6.319c-0.104,0.471-0.57,0.772-1.045,0.667c-0.474-0.104-0.771-0.573-0.666-1.043
               l2.411-10.967c0.021-0.118,0.021-0.311-0.149-0.35c-0.252-0.054-0.331,0.124-0.362,0.261l-0.803,3.659
               c-0.073,0.326-0.4,0.537-0.729,0.464c-0.328-0.072-0.534-0.399-0.463-0.726l0.775-3.527l0.05-0.222l0.112-0.512
               c0.234-1.07,1.245-1.767,2.312-1.632c0.033,0.004,0.073,0.007,0.111,0.016l1.686,0.371l1.676,0.368
               C458.404,231.891,458.438,231.905,458.478,231.918"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M446.297,227.854c0.176-0.805-0.327-1.601-1.134-1.777
               c-0.805-0.177-1.602,0.333-1.776,1.137c-0.177,0.802,0.33,1.597,1.136,1.775C445.326,229.166,446.12,228.657,446.297,227.854"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M441.185,230.184l-2.075,3.672c0,0-0.374,0.674,0.198,0.989
               c0.568,0.315,0.909-0.351,0.909-0.351l1.699-3.072c0,0,0.106-0.241,0.287-0.144c0.178,0.097,0.047,0.351,0.047,0.351l-3.053,5.788
               l1.577,0.347l-0.969,4.41c-0.092,0.419,0.174,0.832,0.592,0.924c0.42,0.092,0.833-0.173,0.924-0.591l0.971-4.41l0.217,0.046
               l0.214,0.045l-0.972,4.413c-0.091,0.419,0.173,0.832,0.593,0.923c0.422,0.095,0.835-0.173,0.926-0.59l0.971-4.411l1.578,0.348
               l-0.341-6.533c0,0-0.014-0.285,0.188-0.3c0.202-0.012,0.2,0.252,0.2,0.252l0.252,3.502c0,0,0.031,0.745,0.678,0.699
               c0.655-0.045,0.596-0.815,0.596-0.815l-0.342-4.206c0,0-0.181-1.23-1.139-1.442l-1.543-0.339l-1.542-0.34
               C441.868,229.142,441.185,230.184,441.185,230.184"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M437.58,225.936c0.176-0.804-0.328-1.601-1.133-1.777
               c-0.805-0.177-1.601,0.333-1.778,1.137c-0.177,0.803,0.332,1.599,1.136,1.775C436.608,227.249,437.402,226.741,437.58,225.936"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M432.469,228.268l-2.075,3.671c0,0-0.376,0.675,0.198,0.99
               c0.568,0.316,0.908-0.348,0.908-0.348l1.699-3.072c0,0,0.107-0.243,0.286-0.146c0.18,0.097,0.047,0.351,0.047,0.351l-3.052,5.787
               l1.578,0.347l-0.971,4.412c-0.091,0.417,0.178,0.831,0.595,0.923c0.417,0.092,0.831-0.174,0.924-0.592l0.969-4.41l0.219,0.047
               l0.214,0.048l-0.973,4.411c-0.09,0.417,0.173,0.832,0.594,0.924c0.418,0.093,0.833-0.173,0.924-0.59l0.972-4.412l1.577,0.348
               l-0.34-6.533c0,0-0.016-0.286,0.187-0.3c0.203-0.014,0.201,0.253,0.201,0.253l0.252,3.5c0,0,0.03,0.746,0.677,0.7
               c0.654-0.046,0.595-0.816,0.595-0.816l-0.341-4.205c0,0-0.179-1.231-1.14-1.442l-1.54-0.339l-1.544-0.339
               C433.151,227.225,432.469,228.268,432.469,228.268"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M449.394,237.072c0.669,0.146,1.327-0.277,1.476-0.947
               c0.148-0.669-0.274-1.329-0.944-1.477c-0.669-0.146-1.331,0.274-1.477,0.945C448.299,236.263,448.722,236.926,449.394,237.072"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M445.659,240.196c-0.088,0.129-0.204,0.417,0.053,0.612
               c0.298,0.228,0.556-0.054,0.556-0.054l1.118-1.954c0,0,0.144-0.117,0.116,0.029l-1.088,4.944h0.004
               c-0.077,0.343,0.139,0.681,0.483,0.758c0.342,0.074,0.682-0.142,0.757-0.485l0.43-1.951c0,0,0.023-0.284,0.249-0.235
               c0.221,0.049,0.126,0.318,0.126,0.318l-0.429,1.949c-0.076,0.345,0.143,0.684,0.486,0.758c0.343,0.076,0.684-0.14,0.759-0.483
               l1.088-4.945c0.028-0.144,0.085-0.024,0.085-0.024l0.2,1.55c0,0,0.082,0.693,0.145,0.737c0.212,0.149,0.505,0.098,0.657-0.117
               c0.097-0.137,0.108-0.308,0.044-0.454l0.008-0.002c-0.008-0.049-0.354-2.074-0.385-2.351c-0.099-0.857-0.595-0.96-1.072-1.079
               c-0.478-0.118-0.766-0.169-0.766-0.169s-0.303-0.079-0.942-0.201c-0.635-0.118-0.903,0.163-1.992,1.799
               c-0.158,0.236-0.677,0.997-0.692,1.047L445.659,240.196z"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M424.761,222.271c0.188-0.849-0.35-1.688-1.2-1.876
               c-0.847-0.187-1.686,0.351-1.871,1.201c-0.188,0.847,0.346,1.689,1.195,1.874C423.732,223.656,424.574,223.119,424.761,222.271"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M420.961,223.667c-1.065-0.135-2.075,0.563-2.311,1.632l-0.112,0.509
               l-0.048,0.224l-0.777,3.526c-0.07,0.33,0.137,0.654,0.467,0.728c0.329,0.071,0.655-0.135,0.727-0.464l0.805-3.658
               c0.029-0.139,0.11-0.315,0.361-0.258c0.174,0.038,0.167,0.229,0.15,0.347l-2.411,10.966c-0.104,0.473,0.191,0.941,0.667,1.045
               c0.474,0.104,0.939-0.197,1.044-0.668l1.391-6.32c0.018-0.069,0.08-0.243,0.299-0.196c0.218,0.048,0.204,0.234,0.193,0.305
               l-1.392,6.318c-0.103,0.472,0.195,0.942,0.667,1.047c0.473,0.103,0.939-0.199,1.046-0.669l2.411-10.967
               c0.031-0.116,0.109-0.29,0.282-0.254c0.25,0.056,0.248,0.25,0.219,0.389l-0.805,3.658c-0.072,0.326,0.137,0.653,0.465,0.726
               c0.329,0.073,0.654-0.137,0.727-0.465l0.775-3.524l0.049-0.225l0.111-0.51c0.236-1.07-0.388-2.127-1.412-2.45
               c-0.033-0.012-0.068-0.023-0.11-0.035l-1.682-0.371l-1.679-0.368C421.037,223.673,420.996,223.671,420.961,223.667"/>
               <line clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.307" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="418.099" y1="230.292" x2="415.143" y2="237.227"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M425.78,231.214c-0.054-0.143-0.172-0.256-0.328-0.289
               c-0.244-0.053-0.484,0.101-0.538,0.344c-0.016,0.071,0,0.202,0,0.202l0.735,2.477c0,0,0.04,0.17,0.01,0.309l-1.044,4.745h0.005
               c-0.074,0.333,0.133,0.656,0.465,0.728c0.33,0.074,0.652-0.134,0.726-0.464l0.412-1.875c0,0,0.025-0.27,0.238-0.225
               c0.213,0.048,0.121,0.305,0.121,0.305l-0.411,1.875c-0.074,0.33,0.137,0.654,0.467,0.727c0.329,0.071,0.656-0.135,0.729-0.465
               l1.045-4.747c0.029-0.14,0.137-0.275,0.137-0.275l1.578-1.792c0,0,0.202-0.262,0.218-0.332c0.054-0.242-0.101-0.484-0.344-0.538
               c-0.162-0.036-0.315,0.02-0.42,0.125l-0.005-0.003c-0.042,0.022-0.829,0.906-1.055,1.049c-0.243,0.158-0.413,0.096-0.413,0.096
               l-0.737-0.163l-0.732-0.161c0,0-0.183-0.016-0.335-0.259c-0.148-0.229-0.488-1.358-0.518-1.397L425.78,231.214z"/>
              <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M427.538,232.267c0.671,0.146,1.33-0.276,1.479-0.947
               c0.147-0.669-0.274-1.329-0.944-1.477c-0.67-0.146-1.329,0.274-1.477,0.945C426.445,231.457,426.87,232.12,427.538,232.267"/>
              <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="427.168,233.967 428.316,235.267 428.438,237.805 426.421,237.361
               424.399,236.917 425.577,234.664   "/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="456.941,77.504 456.98,77.504 456.98,99.654 461.847,99.654
                 461.847,70.718 457.963,70.718 453.481,75.967 453.481,81.045 453.524,81.045   "/>
                    <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="436.893,124.923 436.893,130.997 435.522,130.997 435.522,121.33
                   437.118,121.33 438.872,126.875 438.872,121.33 440.227,121.33 440.227,130.997 438.801,130.997   "/>
                  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M441.151,128.501v-4.675c0-1.512,0.741-2.61,2.45-2.61
                   c1.728,0,2.468,1.098,2.468,2.61v4.675c0,1.498-0.74,2.611-2.468,2.611C441.893,131.112,441.151,130,441.151,128.501
                    M444.445,128.759v-5.189c0-0.583-0.259-0.998-0.844-0.998c-0.568,0-0.824,0.415-0.824,0.998v5.189
                   c0,0.585,0.256,0.997,0.824,0.997C444.187,129.756,444.445,129.344,444.445,128.759"/>
                  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M435.522,134.873h2.409c1.64,0,2.238,0.813,2.238,2.167v2.038
                   c0,1.354-0.599,2.181-2.238,2.181h-0.785v3.28h-1.624V134.873z M437.146,136.198v3.807h0.602c0.555,0,0.795-0.271,0.795-0.799
                   v-2.224c0-0.527-0.24-0.784-0.795-0.784H437.146z"/>
                  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M441.01,142.043v-4.675c0-1.512,0.741-2.609,2.451-2.609
                   c1.726,0,2.467,1.098,2.467,2.609v4.675c0,1.499-0.741,2.608-2.467,2.608C441.751,144.651,441.01,143.542,441.01,142.043
                    M444.304,142.301v-5.19c0-0.585-0.259-0.998-0.843-0.998c-0.569,0-0.826,0.413-0.826,0.998v5.19c0,0.585,0.257,0.997,0.826,0.997
                   C444.045,143.298,444.304,142.886,444.304,142.301"/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="451.772,134.872 449.933,144.538 448.165,144.538 446.324,134.872
                   447.98,134.872 449.091,141.617 449.104,141.617 450.246,134.872   "/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="452.44,134.872 456.319,134.872 456.319,136.197 454.067,136.197
                   454.067,138.964 455.678,138.964 455.678,140.274 454.067,140.274 454.067,143.213 456.319,143.213 456.319,144.538
                   452.44,144.538   "/>
                  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M458.813,140.105v4.434h-1.627v-9.667h2.369c1.638,0,2.237,0.813,2.237,2.167
                   v1.239c0,1.042-0.372,1.655-1.299,1.869l1.555,4.392h-1.711L458.813,140.105z M458.813,136.198v3.008h0.542
                   c0.555,0,0.798-0.285,0.798-0.798v-1.426c0-0.527-0.243-0.784-0.798-0.784H458.813z"/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="462.347,134.872 466.669,134.872 466.669,136.197 465.327,136.197
                   465.327,144.538 463.688,144.538 463.688,136.197 462.347,136.197   "/>
                  <polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFFFFF" points="470.586,140.86 470.586,144.538 468.963,144.538 468.963,140.86
                   467.151,134.872 468.85,134.872 469.832,138.535 469.844,138.535 470.83,134.872 472.383,134.872   "/>
      </a>
      </svg>
```

Comment: Actually only Chrome has implemented it (with a syntax different from the SVG 2 specification). Firefox, Safari and Edge have not.

Comment: is there an alternative method to achieve what I want?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of one way to do it. Another way is to attach mouse event handlers and update the `d` attribute using Javascript.